# What would be a better way to write switching 2 state code in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

So im writing some code for a website that i've implemented which is a simple hide/show function. And i've been thinking about how I can go about writing this or similar code shorter, concise or more efficient.

To be specific, how to easily have a "switch" state that switches between 2 if statements.

```
let selectedArrow = document.getElementsByClassName('arrows');
let state = 0;
for (let i = 0; i < selectedArrow.length; i++) {
    selectedArrow[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
        let id = event.target;
        let target = event.target.parentElement.nextElementSibling;
        if(state === 0) {
            id.style.transform = 'rotate(-90deg)'
            target.style.display = 'none';
            state = 1;
        } else if(state === 1) {
            id.style.transform = 'rotate(0deg)'
            target.style.display = 'grid';
            state = 0;
        }
    });
}
```

This code works perfectly fine, just wondering if others have any other tricks as i'm a beginner coder.

Comment: `function switch` will throw `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token switch`

Comment: where do you set `showState`?

Comment: Have you considered using [`<details>` and `<summary>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/details)?

Comment: Consider https://jsfiddle.net/h65mo7nc/ - use a boolean and a more meaningful name than `state`, iterate with `forEach`, toggle the boolean outside the `if`/`else` (and drop the `function switch`)

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol oh wow, that is really cool, I did not know that existed.
I will gladly save that link, thank you!

Comment: @nietTheDarkAbsol yesterday I spent half an hour doing exactly the same with bootstrap ... why wasn't this question asked yesterday ... :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this helps, here i use marker class in dom to store state:

```js
let bindClick = e => e.onclick = e => e.target.classList.toggle('active');
[...document.querySelectorAll('.arrows')].forEach(bindClick)
```

```css
.arrows {
  border: solid;
  width: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  font: 44px arial;
  margin: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: ease-in 300ms;
}

.active {
  color: red;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class='arrows active'>1</div> <div class='arrows'>2</div> <div class='arrows'>3</div>
<div class='arrows active'>4</div> <div class='arrows'>5</div> <div class='arrows'>6</div>
```

`[...expr]` is used because `forEach` iteration over `NodeList` which returned from `document.querySelectorAll` [dont implemented in some browsers...](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach#Browser_Compatibility) or implemented not so long time ago

---

Here is alternative if you dont want to use styling for manage state represenation:

```js
[...document.querySelectorAll('.arrows')].forEach(e => e.onclick = e => {
  e.target.classList.toggle('active');
  let v = e.target.classList.contains('active');
  e.target.style.transform = `rotate(${v ? -45 : 0}deg)`;
  e.target.style.color = v ? 'red' : 'black';
})
```

```css
.arrows {
  border: solid;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 40px;
  margin: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class='arrows'>1</div> <div class='arrows'>2</div> <div class='arrows'>3</div>
<div class='arrows'>4</div> <div class='arrows'>5</div> <div class='arrows'>6</div>
```

Comment: You aren't doing a mapping transformation, so don't use `.map` for a simple iteration, use `.forEach`.

Comment: @VLAZ i know, but author asking for shorter solution =)

Comment: Are you code-golfing or writing code that others should use?

Comment: @VLAZ you are right, i must correct my answer, thanks

Comment: @StrangerintheQ I really like the first solution, thanks for sharing!
Btw, where does the animation with the rotation come from, css?

Comment: @FrankPettersson yes it is css parameter `transition: 300ms`

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, `function switch` will error out - this doesn't need the `switch` (it's reserved anyway). Secondly, you can use some fancy ternaries and template literals:

```
let selectedArrow = document.getElementsByClassName('arrows');
let state = 0;
for (let i = 0; i < selectedArrow.length; i++) {
    selectedArrow[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
        let id = event.target;
        let target = event.target.parentElement.nextElementSibling;
        id.style.transform = `rotate(${-90 + (state * 90)})`;
        target.style.display = id ? "grid" : "none";
        state = state ? 0 : 1;
    });
}
```

Comment: `-90 + (state * 90)` is clear as mud. If you're going to use template literals, at least do something logical like `state ? 0 : -90`